# using SearchView with toolbar, How to open keyboard when activity loads?

Tags: android, searchview

I have tried the other possible answer provided in stackoverflow but none of them is working so I am posting it here again. 
The problem is I want to open the softkeyboard  automatically when the `activity` opens, but none of the ways I have tried is working.

My Activity code where I am setting `SearchView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) SelectCityActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(SelectCityActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
        searchView.setQueryHint(searchHint);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        final SearchView finalSearchView = searchView;
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    showInputMethod(view);
                    finalSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();
                }
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                valueAdapter.getFilter().filter(Methods.capitalize(s));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

And menu xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: did you tried requestFocus?

Comment: Thanks, requestFocus is working :D

Comment: But the answer which worked for me was just calling requestFocus(), I didn't try that answer where you are doing something with actionbar.

Comment: I will edit it to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call this line in your code

```
searchView.requestFocus();
```

That's it.

Comment: @SoH what do you want to say ?

Comment: sorry for the comment. It does not work by itself is what I wanted to write.

Comment: For me it works if I also add the following:searchTransactionsSearchView.isIconified = false

Answer (score 0):

Put below code on **onCreate** of Activity:

```
((InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

try this to force open soft keyboard:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```